# Ionic2 folder structure missing app folder

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm starting to learn Ionic2, I have create a new empty project with `ionic start myproject blank --v2` and everything works correctly if I do `ionic serve`.

Then I read [this](https://moduscreate.com/ionic-2-project-structure/) tutorial and many others. All of them state that the ionic folder structure should have an `app` folder:

If I look at my project folder structure I can't see any app folder. My structure looks so:

```
.
├── hooks
├── plugins
├── scss
├── www
│   ├── index.html  
│   ├── css
│   ├── img 
│   ├── js
│   └── lib
├── bower.json
├── config.xml
├── gulpfile.js
├── ionic.project
└── package.json
```

Now I'd like to follow [this](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-tutorial-lets-create-our-first-application/) tutorial in order to build my first application but as you can see the folder structure of that example is different from mine and as an Ionic beginner I'm a little confused.

FIY (if it matters):

I'm referring to [this](https://github.com/driftyco?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=ionic2) page for the templates.

```
cordova -v: 6.2.0
ionic -v: 1.7.15
```

Answer (score 1):

It might because your Node.js needs update.

First use `node --version` in your terminal (if you use Mac) to check the version of your Node.js. I had the same problem with you when node version in my Mac was v5.10.1 and solved it by using `brew upgrade node` to upgrade my Node.js to v6.3.1.

After updating your Node.js to the latest version just use `ionic start myProject --v2` to create a new project and then the new project you created should have /app inside.