# Ionic2 CLI generated code missing src folder on Windows 10

Tags: ionic2

I have often noticed that using Ionic2 cli to start a new project, generates code that is missing the src folder. It is not clear how to fix this issue.

I generated a brand new project using the command:

```
ionic start webapp sidemenu --V2
```

and it generates folders as shown in the screenshot. I am on Windows 10, node version 6.9.4, ionic version 2.2.1

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "webapp: An Ionic project",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

[image: Ionic generated code missing src folder]

Answer (score 2):

I've same issue and find the anwser here : [Ionic2 folder structure missing app folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447783/ionic2-folder-structure-missing-app-folder)

Use "--v2" option to force the ionic2 and DL all the folders/files

```
ionic start myProject --v2
```